# How can I use regex in python to extract information from a legal description

Tags: python, regex, gis

I am trying to use regex to extract degrees/minutes/seconds and feet in a legal description for a land parcel.  An example of a written legal description would be something like this:

> CONT FROM THE PT ON THE NWLY ROW LN OF CO RD NO 31 N 56D 54M 00S W 365
>   FT TH S 32D 06M 00S W 91/89 FT TH S 61D 54M 00S E 335/77 FT TO THE
>   NWLY ROW OF SD CO RD NO 31 TH N 32D 06M 00S E 62/62 FT TO THE POB EXC
>   THAT PART CONVEYED IN BOOK 1132 PAGE 473   0/5900A

I have written a regex that will go through this and find the area's that are what I am looking for such as: **N 32D 06M 00S E 62/62 FT.**
The problem is sometimes the feet are not written directly after the degrees/minutes/seconds. For example it might say instead: **N 32D 06M 00S E** along the road for 62/62 FT.
The "along the road for" is the part that messes with my regex.

Is there a good way to get around this?  Below is an example of my code

Input for user:

`legal_input=input("Paste legal description from RW here: ")`

Regex code to find cogo:

```
cogo_rgx = re.compile(r'([N]{,2}[S]{,2} \w{,1}\d{,2}D{,1} \d{,2}M{,1} \d{,2}S{,1}\s{,2}\w) (\s{,2}\d{1,4}\W{,1}\d{,2} FT){,1}') 

full_legal=cogo_rgx.findall(legal_input)
```

Print message:

`print("\nCogo below: \n")`

Print the key from the dictionary followed by the value(dms followed by feet). This makes it easier to read:

```
for key, value in full_legal:
   print(key, value)
```

Comment: Do the matches you're looking for *always* eventually end in `FT`? (I'm wondering because your final group has `{,1}` - the group including the `FT` needs to match only *zero or one* time according to your current RE, not *exactly one* time..?)

Comment: That's a good question. They always should end in FT but unfortunately there are quite a few typos in these legal descriptions and things get left out pretty frequently.  I wish it was always perfect but that's why I had to put in a few of the {,1} and {,2} parts of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `((?:N|S) \d{2}D \d{2}M \d{2}S (?:E|W) )(?:.)*?(?=\d+(?:\/\d+)? FT)(\d+(?:\/\d+)? FT)`

and combine capture groups 1 and 2

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s7ghZw/2)

Comment: Thank you very much I will try this out as soon as I get a chance.  I am pretty new to python so I appreciate any help or ideas on how to do things.